# Cloudinary Invalid Cloudinary Config Provided

Tags: cloudinary, keystonejs

I am new to KeystoneJS and I am having a small problem concerning my deployment on Heroku.
This is my website: http://jeroendruwe.herokuapp.com/, when I navigate to the admin section (http://jeroendruwe.herokuapp.com/keystone/signin)
I get the Invalid Cloudinary Config Provided error

Papertrailapp log: http://pastebin.com/Yn8Pdttz

I've read the documentation (http://keystonejs.com/docs/configuration/#services-cloudinary). The weird thing is that when I try one of these (in keystone.js), the whole site stops working:

```
keystone.set('cloudinary config', { cloud_name: 'my-cloud', api_key: 'abc', api_secret:     '123' });
// or
keystone.set('cloudinary config', 'cloudinary://api_key:api_secret@cloud_name' );
```

So what I've done at the moment is set the property in the keystone.init(...'cloudinary config': 'cloudinary://...'). I've also added the url to the CLOUDINARY_URL environment variable in the .env file

How can I fix this issue?

Can somebody also explain what the variables in the .env file do? There is 1 in the root and another one in the node_modules/dotenv folder, these files are not pushed to git so how do they get used?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let me start by answering your last question first. The `.env` file is used by the `dotenv` module, which loads the variables/values in the `.env` file and makes them available to your application in `process.env`. Make sure you call the `.load()` method as early as possible in your code.

```
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.load();
```

You should also know that Heroku has two other means to configure environment variables (See [Configuration and Config Variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#setting-up-config-vars-for-a-deployed-application)). One via your application dashboard and another via their CLI.

Using the Heroku Dashboard, just fill in the `NEW_KEY` and `NEW_VALUE` fields, then press `Save`.

[image: Configuring variables via Heroku Dashboard]

Using the Heroku CLI, just use the `heroku config:set` command.

```
$ heroku config:set CLOUDINARY_URL=cloudinary://api_key:api_secret@cloud_name
Adding config vars and restarting myapp... done, v12
CLOUDINARY_URL: cloudinary://api_key:api_secret@cloud_name
```

If you're using Heroku, I suggest you use one of these to methods to set the `CLOUDINARY_URL` for your application in production.

Now back to your original question. This error typically means that there's something wrong with the Cloudinary configuration (i.e. it's either incorrect or completely missing). Without seeing the actual code that you're using it would be impossible to pinpoint the exact problem.

I'm going to assume that your replacing the `api_key`, `api_secret` and `cloud_name` with the actual values. That said, I would still double check to make sure those values are correct.

In my Heroku deployments, I use `dovenv` to set the environment variables in development, and use the either the Heroku Dashboard or CLI to set them in production.

If you're still having difficulties, please post the actual code your using (omitting your actual api key, of course), including the content of your `.env` file.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer!
I fixed it by adding CLOUDINARY_URL as config var on my heroku dashboard. I now understand the concept of the dotenv module but why are there 2 .env files and how does the root .env file gets used (it only contains a MANDRILL_API_KEY) http://imgur.com/gwVWiQL

Comment: The `.env` files within in `node_modules\dotenv`, if I'm not mistaken, are used for unit testing. The only `.env` file that is relevant is the one in your app. You can safely ignore the ones in `node_modules\dotenv`.